Shockley Equation works better at higher temperatures
I have been doing some work as part of my undergraduate labs, and currently, the experiment is to determine the constant $e/k_B$ from the I-V response of a germanium PN junction. However, I've encountered something strange, and I don't know how to explain it.
From the Shockley Equation, we know that the I-V response for an ideal semiconductor is given (theoretically) by:
$$
I = K\left( e^\left( \frac{eV}{k_B T}\right)-1 \right)
$$
Where $K$ is a constant depenent on recombination, the bandgap, and other factors. After getting the data for $I$ vs $V$ for a germanium PN junction at a variety of different temperatures, ranging from $-150°C$ to $50°C$, I found that the values for $e/k_B$ that I obtain from the diode get considerably closer to the expected value of $~1.16 \times 10^4$. This really confused me, and I still can't figure out why this would happen. I expected to obtain a better estimate at lower temperatures, since lower temperature would (intuitively) mean less noise. Does anyone have some sort of plausible explanation, or some sources I could read to make an educated guess about the cause of this observation?

It might well be a fluke. But I guess maybe it does make sense: the low temperature part might be dominated by impurities rather than the thermal expression shown above.
